# How can I get a limited no of friends from facebook using fbconnect and FQL

Tags: iphone, fbconnect, facebook-fql

How can I get a limited no of friends from facebook using fbconnect and FQL

Answer (score 1):

FQL supports the LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT something, something FROM table LIMIT 10
```